# why do I get error with flask form submission?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I get this "Form submission failed!
Status: NOT FOUND 404
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again" error when I hit submit on my form.

`   from flask import Flask, render_template, request

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def index():
   return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def submit():
  if request.method=="POST":
    name = request.form["name"]
    email = request.form["email"]
    subject = request.form["subject"]
    message = request.form["message"]
    print(name,email,subject,message)
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__=="__main__":
 app.debug=True
 app.run()
```

`
please help out

Answer (score 0):

Your `@app.route('/')` has been repeated twice with same first argument 
so you need to specify an address(url) for your submission page as shown below

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST','GET'])
def submit():
    #...
```